# Failed to upgrade pip3 on Mac with Homebrew Python

Tags: python, macos, pip, sudo

I failed at upgrading pip3 on mac and get confusing (for me) answers in the terminal:

```
> which python
/usr/bin/python

> pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

> which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

> python3 -V
Python 3.6.4

> pip3 -V
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

> sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

> sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip3
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip3
```

Why can't I have pip3 upgraded to 9.0?

---

Solution was to force reinstall:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip --force-reinstall
```

Comment: And when you run the last command without sudo?

Comment: @gonczor writing issues

Comment: sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip --force-reinstall did the job. From what I found it might be a mix within pip2 and pip3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Verify that `/usr/local/bin/pip3 --version` is 9.0.1. If not:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I.e., use `pip` package from that particular Python version.